# How do I get the second derivative of theta in Word?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I know you can get the first derivative of theta in Microsoft Word by typing \dot{\theta}, but I'm not sure how to get its second derivative.

Can somebody please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is not Word, but LaTex code into Word equations.

The two dots that you want can be got with `\ddot`, like:

[image: ddot]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean theta? Hold the Alt key and type 952.

[image: Theta examples lower-upper]

*********Edited after downvote and after poster corrected errors

The diaeresis can be entered from the symbol menu (Character Code 0308). Have your cursor after the theta before inserting. If this will be a frequent symbol, consider recording a macro and assigning a keyboard shortcut.